# map.get() method isn't working with D3 v6

Tags: javascript, reactjs, d3.js, force-layout

I am new to D3.js and I am trying to make some animation with my graph,
but I can't resolve a problem with the `.get()` method called on a `d3.map` for D3 version 6.
When I run the code it throws an error:

> nodeById.get is not a function

My code is based on: https://bl.ocks.org/ctufts/bd6956a45ea69734f5909c8b526c13b5

```
//some fetch data in json file
d3.json("someURLjsonfile").then(function (graph) {
        
let nodes = graph.nodes,
    nodeById = d3.map(nodes, function (d) {
      return d.id;
    }),
    links = graph.links,
    bilinks = [];
            

    links.forEach(function (link) {
    var  s = nodeById.get(link.source),  // <-- error
         t = nodeById.get(link.target),  // <-- error
         i = {}; // intermediate node
         nodes.push(i);
         links.push({
                    source: s,
                    target: i
                }, {
                    source: i,
                    target: t
                });
                bilinks.push([s, i, t]);
            });
```

Answer (score 4):

Your problem is caused by some rather unfortunate re-design of the API. As of D3 v6 the [`d3-collection`](https://github.com/d3/d3-collection) module was deprecated and removed from the D3 bundle. That module contained the [`d3.map()`](https://github.com/d3/d3-collection#map) constructor method that would create a [`d3.map`](https://github.com/d3/d3-collection#maps) object, i.e. one of D3's internal map implementations mimicking the native JavaScript [`Map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map). This method has been around a while but has lost importance once ES6 feature became available and was therefore removed.

Sadly, with version 2 of the `d3-array` module a method with the same name was introduced which is basically equivalent to the native `array.map()` or `Array.from()` methods:

> [#](https://github.com/d3/d3-array#map) d3.**map**(*iterable*, *mapper*) · [Source](https://github.com/d3/d3-array/blob/main/src/map.js)
>
> Returns a new array containing the mapped values from *iterable*, in order, as defined by given *mapper* function. Equivalent to [array.map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) and [Array.from](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from):

Since `d3-array` **v2** was introduced to the bundle with the same version 6 that also removed `d3-collection` the `d3.map` property is still available, however, its meaning has changed.

Your code seems to have been written for D3 <v6 and breaks because of the changes laid out above. The new `d3.map()` is a mapper function not a constructor; it returns an array which does not feature a `.get()` method, hence, the error.

To fix the issue you can change your code to directly use the built-in `Map` object instead:

```
nodeById = new Map(Array.from(nodes, d => [d.id, d]));
```

With the rest untouched your code should be running as expected.

Comment: And unfortunately, observables examples are full of this problem.